# Run Debian program compiled on Ubuntu with Lazarus

Tags: debian, lazarus

When compiling any source developed in Lazarus in Ubuntu, it does the same thing normally, but in Debian with the `./Test` command, it gives the following error:

```
Targeting Failure
```

The Debian version is in Portuguese. The program can be as simple as it is, even just displaying a simple text output. The systems have the same 32-bit architecture. Is it missing a library or incompatibility? I can not compile directly in Debian, because it is a VPS and I only have SSH access.

Here is the source code:

```
program Test;

uses
  SysUtils;

var
iParam: string;

begin
  iParam := ParamStr(1);
  Writeln(iParam);
end.
```

Comment: Segmentation fault. Do some debugging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you tell me how, because I can not compile in Debian, I only have remote access through SSH

Comment: Going to be difficult without the ability to debug and diagnose the problem. Take steps to remedy that.